# Read SQL connection from ini

Tags: c#, sql

I would like to build an SQL Compact connection from ini file.

In my ini file the connection path is the following:

```
DataBasePath=D:/Database/TrainingDatabase.sdf
```

And my code is the following:

```
public static SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source="+SQLPath);
```

I can read out the database path from the ini file without any problem, but I can't open the connection, because of this error:

> Database cannot be null, the empty string, or string of only whitespace.

Comment: First make sure the returned value (by reading the file) is not null or empty, if not null or empty, you can call the `.Trim()` to get rid of any possible white space.

Comment: If that is a _static global SqlCeConnection_ then how do you initialize the SQLPath string? We need to see the code.

Comment: This is just a simple string manipulation inside your .ini or .txt file.

Comment: Show the code reading the ini file. Put a breakpoint to verify the ini file is being read correctly. Or just use a config file and the appropriate classes.

Answer (score 1):

Ok lets just say you have text file named CONNECTION.TXT and contains below text.

```
Data Source = ServerName
Initial Catalog = DatabaseName
Integrated Security = false
User Id = sa
Password = 123456
```

below code will read your text file line by line

```
  string serverName, databaseName, userId, password;
  bool integratedSecurity;

  int counter = 0;
  string line;

  // Read the file and display it line by line.
  System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\CONNECTION.txt");
  while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    if (line.Contains("Data Source"))
      serverName = line.Replace("Data Source = ", "");
    else if (line.Contains("Initial Catalog"))
      databaseName = line.Replace("Initial Catalog = ", "");
    else if (line.Contains("Integrated Security"))
      integratedSecurity = Convert.ToBoolean(line.Replace("Integrated Security = ", ""));
    else if (line.Contains("User Id"))
      userId = line.Replace("User Id = ", "");
    else if (line.Contains("Password"))
      password = line.Replace("Password = ", "");

    Console.WriteLine(line);
    counter++;
  }

  file.Close();
```

Comment: Well, fine, but the OP says he has no problem reading **the INI file**

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your environment and the technology used (WinForms, ASP.NET, WPF ???) I can only show a pseudocode that tries to highlight your problem

This line is probably inside a class

```
public class MyApp
{
    public static SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source="+SQLPath);
    ......
}
```

this makes the `conn` variable a class level global static variable that is initialized sometime BEFORE the first usage of the class ([C# Reference Static Field Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx)).
This means that also the `SQLPath` variable should be a static otherwise it will be unusable by the other static.

So we need to have

```
public class MyApp
{
    public static string SQLPath = MyApp.GetPathFromINIFile();
    public static SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source="+SQLPath);
    ......

    public static string GetPathFromINIFile()
    {
        // read and return the path from the INI key
        ....
        return dbPath;
    }
}
```

But this is really weak. If you move for any reason the initialization of `SQLPath` AFTER the initialization of `conn` you will get the initial error and the head scratch begins.

I can only suggest to kill these static global variables (at least the SqlCeConnection) and create a local variable for the SqlCeConnection only when you need to use it.

```
public class MyApp
{
    public static string SQLPath = MyApp.GetPathFromINIFile();
    public static string GetPathFromINIFile()
    {
        ....
        return dbPath;
    }

    public bool UpdateCustomerTable(Customer cs)
    {
        using(SqlCeConnection cnn = new SqlCeConnection(MyApp.SQLPath))
        {
            ......
        }
    }
}
```

In this way you don't keep a resource alive for the duration of your program and avoid to cross dangerous waters like the `Static Field Initialization` rules.